# Why am I receiving this error: " Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"? "?

Tags: r

I have this assignment:

**Participants were asked to estimate how many minutes they spend
    per day on Instagram. The results of this question are in the 'usage_duration' 
    column. Let's take a look at the distribution of their answers. Think of an 
    appropriate visualization for this and describe what you see in it. Include 
    a vertical line that shows the mean usage for the entire data set.**

Here is the data set(usage_duration column):

```
  |usage_duration|
  |   54.0       |   
  |   6576.0     |   
  |   6.5        |  
  |   3.5        |
  |   346        | 
  |   456        |
```

Here is the code that I am using to determine whats being asked in the question:

```
  mean_of_duration <- mean(as.numeric(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration), na.rm = TRUE)

  ggplot(SurveyInsta, mapping=aes(x = Usage_duration)) +
  geom_histogram(color="blue", fill="red", color="Average") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean_of_duration, color="Average"), show.legend = TRUE)
```

however, I am getting this error:

> **Error**: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?

But I am not even sure if I am doing the thing that's actually being asked, so if you think that I misunderstood the assignment please let me know.

Comment: I'd guess that `usage_duration` is not numeric - it may be of type character, or factor. What does `str(SurveyInsta)` show you?

Comment: @neilfws good boy, thank you!